# How do I make the random array choice the value of my state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to randomly select items from my 'items' array, how do I make the randomly selected item the value of the 'randomItem' state?
Heres what I have so far.

```
var items = ['joe', 'joe', 'mama', 'one direction went the other direction'];

this.state.randomItem items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]





export default class App extends Component {

state = {
      randomItem: '',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the random item to the component, and then set the state with it.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { item: props.item };
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>{item}</div>
    );
  }

};

const items = ['joe', 'joe', 'mama', 'one direction went the other direction'];

const randomItem =  items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]


ReactDOM.render(
  <Example item={randomItem} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```